# Observable zip() throws an error all the time?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I have a service which populates some data:

```
service.getMyPojo1Parameters(this, intent);
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(params -> {
            onMyPojoParametersUpdated(params.first);
        }, throwable -> {
            // showError
        });
```

Unfortunately, `params` are never valid and it immediately jumps to `showError` section? Here is the implementation of the `getMyPojo1Parameters()` Method:

```
public Observable<Pair<MyPojo1, Boolean>> getMyPojo1Parameters(Context context, Intent aIntent) {
        
        Observable<Pair<MyPojo1, Boolean>> resolvePojoParamsObservable = resolvePlace(context, data1, data2);
        Observable<Pair<MyPojoExtended, Boolean>> aSide = resolvePojoParamsObservable
                .flatMap(myPojo1BooleanPair -> {
                    // stuff
                });

        resolvePojoParamsObservable = resolvePlace(context, data3, data3);
        Observable<Pair<MyPojoExtended, Boolean>> bSide = resolvePojoParamsObservable
                .flatMap(myPojo1BooleanPair -> {
                    // stuff
                });


        Observable<Pair<MyPojo1, Boolean>> zip = Observable.zip(aSide, bSide, (a, b) -> {
                    MyPojo1 myPojo1 = new MyPojo1(a.first, b.first, currentDate, currentTime);
                    boolean b = a.second || b.second;
                    return Pair.create(myPojo1, b);
                }
        );
        return zip;
}
```

I guess the zip method is erroneous: A breakpoint at `return Pair.create(MyPojo1, b);` is never being called, whereas the `return zip;` seem to be valid and is not null..

Timber.e logcat or throwable:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.Double com.ralfi.example.models.Location.realmGet$lat()' on
> a null object reference
>
> 03-22 16:20:31.683 29377-29377/com.ralfi.example E/ResultMyPojoActivity:     > at com.ralfi.example.utils.MyRestService.lambda$getMyPojo1Parameters$0$MyRestService(MyRestService.java:122)
>
> 03-22 16:20:31.683 29377-29377/com.ralfi.example
> E/ResultMyPojoActivity:     at
> com.ralfi.example.utils.MyRestService$$Lambda$0.apply(Unknown
> Source:0)

Comment: Please provide that exception and stacktrace which goes into the showError section.

Comment: @akarnokd Yes, I forgot. Done!

Comment: Okay, so what do you think what and where the problem is?

Comment: To be less cryptic, you have a `NullPointerException` because you deference a null `Location` object when invoking a `lat()` method on line 122. This is not an RxJava problem and we can't help you much since there is no way to know which line in the question corresponds to line 122 as well as the method invocation `lat()` is not even shown.

Comment: In your StackTrace you can read exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Thnxs guys, I also figured out now, that my backend does not populate my MyPojo object so it is null.